# Module script throwing error "attempt to call a nil value"

Tags: lua, roblox

Here is my code

```
local module = {}

function module.function_name(target)
    _G.target = target
    local target = game.Players:WaitForChild(tostring(_G.target))
    script.ScreenGUI:Clone().Parent = target.PlayerGui
end

return module
```

But it returns

```
require(game.Workspace.code.ModuleScript).function_name("ihatescauming1234"):1: attempt to call a nil value
```

What i have tried:
Changing

```
_G.target = target
```

to

```
game.players.localplayer
```

i thought it would work before i realized i am running this on the server side

Comment: make sure you're requiring the right module. print the keys

Comment: I am requiring the right module, also how do I print the keys?

Comment: for k,v in pairs(require(yourmodule)) do print(k) end    if you don't know that you probably should learn a few Lua basics befor doing more complex things.

Comment: i have never worked with module scripts before so i just used tutorial also I usually don't use for loops in lua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so there's only ONE problem lol! This is why OOP may be confusing to someone

your code:

```lua
local module = {}

function module.function_name(target)
    _G.target = target
    local target = game.Players:WaitForChild(tostring(_G.target))
    script.ScreenGUI:Clone().Parent = target.PlayerGui
end

return module
```

the fix:

```lua
local module = {}
module.__index = module

function module.function_name(target)
    _G.target = target
    local target = game.Players:WaitForChild(tostring(_G.target))
    script.ScreenGUI:Clone().Parent = target.PlayerGui
end

return module
```